# Fixed expired accounts in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have an Oracle 11g server that's used for PHP development. Recently, I had a [problem logging into the Enterprise Manager](https://serverfault.com/questions/145753/cannot-log-into-oracle-enterprise-manager-11g-ora-28001) due to expired passwords. I've already changed settings so passwords no longer expire and I've unlocked all users. However, the user manager shows most built-in users as expired. How can I fix that? (If I just set a password for each expired account I guess that whatever services are using it will no longer be able to log in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

ALTER USER user ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

If you want that the user is no longer expired you have to change the password (as far as i know). Anyway for those system users is pretty normal they're expired and locked. Instead here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm he's suggesting to change immediately default passwords (as normal procedure) and the users are locked down for security reason.

Comment: I already did that so they're no longer locked. However, the query `SELECT USERNAME, ACCOUNT_STATUS, EXPIRY_DATE FROM DBA_USERS;` still reports them as EXPIRED.

Comment: UNlock and expired are different things.
Try to do ALTER USER XXXXX account unlock identified by YYYYYYYYY;

Comment: What's `YYYYYYYYY` supposed to be? They are system users that were not created by me. Can I just set a random password?

Comment: That's supposed to be a new password. If you want that the user is no longer expired you have to change the password (as far as i know).
Anyway for those system users is pretty normal they're expired and locked. Instead here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm he's suggesting to change immediately default passwords (as normal procedure) and the users are locked down for security reason.

Comment: Alright, I was under the impression that they were like system users in Unix, where they're not even supposed to have a password. I've set a password for them all and Oracle still seems to be running :) Thank you.

Comment: For the records, perhaps you should add your previous comment to the answer.

Comment: did it :) 
I still don't know exactly how it works here

Answer (score 0):

Are these users using the "default" profile ? If so, maybe you can check what are the policies attached to this policy ?

Comment: All users belong to DEFAULT except WKSYS (WKSYS_PROF) and DBSNMP (MONITORING_PROFILE). What exactly do you need to know? I only set PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME to UNLIMITED some time after passwords expired and users got locked.