# Oracle sysman password reset and enterprise manager

Tags: oracle

We are running oracle 10g.yesterday we had to reset sysman(and all other sys acounts)user with alter user command.
Password change command worked by oracle enterprise manager does not see the database running. As per oracle docs,we did change the password(and encryption setting) and restarted the dbconsole service. Password does get encrypted after restarted but em still does not see the database online.

Are we missing any other important step?

Thanks
Aboxy

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/145753/cannot-log-into-oracle-enterprise-manager-11g-ora-28001) will probably help you.